# Set multiple options in response headers flask

Tags: python, flask, response-headers

How can we set multiple options for headers in flask. For example: I want to set two options in **Cache-Control** headers one is **max-age** and other is **public/private**. How do I do it in Flask ?. Currently I have implemented this.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, json, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

book_list = ['Peaceful Warrior', 'The Monk who sold his ferrari', 'Lord of the Rings', 'Game of Thrones', 'The True Name', 'The Da Vinci Code',
            'Angels and Demons', 'Fear of Flying', 'Harry Potter and Half Blood Prince']

# create a in-memory book-store
books = [{'id': id, 'name': book} for id, book in enumerate(book_list, 1)]
@app.route('/books', methods=['GET'])
def get_books():
    if 'name' in request.args:
        req_books = [book for book in books if book['name'] == request.args['name']]
        js = json.dumps(req_books)
        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public'
        resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=20'

    elif 'id' in request.args:
        req_books = [book for book in books if book['id'] == request.args['id']]
        js = json.dumps(req_books)
        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public'
    else:
        js = json.dumps(books)
        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public'

    return resp
```

Finally my response should have headers in this form:-

```
Cache-Control: public
Cache-Control: max-age=20
```

Answer (score 7):

`resp.headers` is a python dictionary so it maps the key 'Cache-Control' to one value.  When you set it twice, you're overwriting the value you previously set.  Fortunately you can use a comma separated list with these headers:

```
resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=20'
```